# onclick listener working only in particular order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created table https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li3s7.jpg on click of tick mark a modal opens https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiDsr.jpg on click of accept the values must be inserted into database but this happens if i do it in order from top to bottom i.e from 1st person then next..if I start from random point like I click the accept button of 4th person in the starting then null values are inserted..please help me?

```
 <!-- html code for tick button and accept -->
<td>                                 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{pl.id}}_1"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i></button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id= "{{pl.id}}_1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Do You want to accept <b>{pl.employee.emp_name|title }} </b> leave?</h4>
      </div>
      <form action={% url 'm_manage:accept' %}  method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" > Notify Via Email<br></p>
        <p><label for="message">Message </label>
        <textarea rows="3" name="message" id="message" class="form-control input-md"></textarea></p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer" id="{{pl.id}}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="accept_{{pl.id}}" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </td>


<!--my jQuery call---->
$(document).on('click','[id^="accept_"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    var v_id=$(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    // tried msg
    var msg=$('#message').val();
    // tried getElementbyId
    // var msg_1=document.getElementById("message").value;
    var check=$('#email').is(':checked');
    console.log(msg);
    // console.log(msg_1);
    console.log(check);
    console.log(v_id);
```

Comment: Seems you are using multiple element with same id, create `email` and `message` as `id="message_{{pl.id}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifier in HTML must be **unique**, duplicate identifiers creates invalid HTML.

You can use class selector to target elements and DOM traversal method to target desired elements.

Additionally use `data-*` custom attribute to store arbitrary data which can be fetched using `.data()` method.

Modify you HTML as

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id= "{{pl.id}}_1" role="dialog" data-id="{{pl.id}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Do You want to accept <b>{pl.employee.emp_name|title }} </b> leave?</h4>
      </div>
      <form action={% url 'm_manage:accept' %}  method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="email" class="email" > Notify Via Email<br></p>
        <p><label for="message">Message </label>
        <textarea rows="3" name="message" class="message" class="form-control input-md"></textarea></p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accept" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '.accept', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
    var v_id = modal.data('id');
    var msg = modal.find('.message').val();
    var check = modal.find('.email').is(':checked');
    console.log(v_id, msg, check);
});
```

Comment: It worked....Thanks a lot.....Really thankful to you...Can you explain why you used data-id.....Is using id the root cause for the problem?

Comment: Could you tell the right platform to learn the basics related to js?

Comment: @divya, using duplicate id is the root cause for the problem, as ID selector `#yourId` only target the first element then stop. `data-id` to store arbitrary data. [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)